# Asp.Net Core 2 Replace Open Id Authentication options in service collection at run time

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, openid-connect

How would you replace authentication options in an IServiceCollection in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

In ConfigureServices:

```
AddAuthentication((o) =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (o) =>
{
    o.LoginPath = Constants.LoginPath;
}).AddOpenIdConnect(ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider);
```

Let's say my client id has changed at run-time, I want to reload the configuration, so I watch for changes in my appsettings.json.

Replacing the configuration by removing it and adding it back into the services does not apply the configuration.

```
Configuration.GetReloadToken().RegisterChangeCallback(OnConfigurationChanged(authServices), new Object());
private Action<object> OnConfigurationChanged(IServiceCollection authServices)
{
    return o =>
    {
        Action<OpenIdConnectOptions> action = ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider;

        //Replace the existing open id connection options
        authServices.Remove(authServices.FirstOrDefault(s => typeof(IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>).Equals(s.ServiceType)));
        authServices.Configure(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, action);
    };
}


private void ConfigureOpenIdConnectProvider(OpenIdConnectOptions opts)
{
    var provider = Configuration.GetSection("OAuthClientProvider").Get<OAuthClientProvider>();
    opts.ClientId = provider.ClientId;
    opts.ClientSecret = provider?.ClientSecret ?? string.Empty;
    opts.Authority = provider.Authority;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add a new scheme in run-time:

```
private void AddGoogleScheme(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     var googleHandlerType = typeof(GoogleOptions).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler");
     var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
     provider.AddScheme(new AuthenticationScheme("Google", "Google", googleHandlerType));
}
```

We can create our own configure, but we don't need Google configure. So, you can remove Google configure:

```
var googleConfigureOptions = services.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>));
services.Remove(googleConfigureOptions);
```

You have to create and register configure options:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, OpenIdConnectConfigurator<GoogleOptions>>();
```

Implementation of our configure options:

```
internal class OpenIdConnectConfigurator<TOptions> : IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions> where TOptions : RemoteAuthenticationOptions
{
    public void Configure(TOptions options)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public void Configure(string name, TOptions options)
    {
      if(name == "Google") // name == "YourScheme"
      {
        // you can get data from DB or other source
        // options.ClientId = ...
        // options.ClientSecret = ...
      } else {
        // Facebook or other IDP
      }
    }
}
```

And if you override options in DB (for instance) then you must clear cache.
Why?

1. Google handler inherits AuthenticationHandler
2. In AuthenticationHandler we have the InitializeAsync method.
3. InitializeAsync method gets options from OptionsMonitor.
4. OptionsMonitor gets options from cache or create new and adds to
   cache.

Of course, you should write it in clean/better way :)
For instance: you can create your own AddGoogle() method which registers everything (then you don't need any IDPs in Startup).
All above codes should show you have to do that. If you have questions, just let me know :)

Comment: My original question was how to replace an existing scheme with new options at runtime, not add a scheme. This solution does not work as expected. Even after removing the scheme and adding it a new instance and registering a new options, the old options are still used.

Comment: Yes, the old options are still used, because you get it from cache :)
So you have to:
1. inject your options `IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>`
2. inject cache `IOptionsMonitorCache<GoogleOptions>`
3. override options
4. clear the cache.
5. Remember that you should update DB or other store where you keep your options :)

You can also override options in `IOptionsMonitorCache<GoogleOptions>` by using remove and add methods. Source code to IOptionsMonitorCache: https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/IOptionsMonitorCache.cs